# jQuery Ajax Image Upload and Preview implementation is refreshing the page which is not expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to upload and preview the image using jQuery Ajax. But it is reloading page whenever I am choosing image file only. One thing I noticed here is that, it is not reloading the page if I am choosing files other than image file. I have checked for the solution online and added all the possible solutions suggested for this i.e  `contentType: false` and `event.preventDefault();` but it is still not working as expected

HTML Code is as below

```
<form id="createCategory">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input name="Name" />
    <br />
    <label>Description</label>
    <input name="Description" />
    <br />
    <label>Image</label>
    <input id="inpImageURL" name="ImageURL" type="hidden" />
    <input id="inpImageUpload" name="Image" type="file"/>
    <div class="thumb">
        <img id="imgUploadImage" src="#" alt="your image" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

jQuery Code is as below

```
$("#inpImageUpload").change(function (event) {
        debugger;
        event.preventDefault();

        var element = this;

        var formData = new FormData();
        var totalFiles = element.files.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
            var file = element.files[i];
            formData.append("Photo", file);
        }

         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: '/Shared/UploadImage',
             dataType: 'json',
             data: formData,
             processData: false,
             contentType: false

         })
        .done(function (response) {
            debugger;
            alert('ajax was called success');
            //console.log(response);
            //if (response.Success) {
            //    //$("#imgUploadImage").attr("src", response.inpImageURL);
            //    //$("#inpImageURL").val(response.inpImageURL);
            //    alert('ajax was called success');
            //}
        })
        .fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, txtStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Failure AJAX Call");
        });



    });
```

ASP.Net MVC code is below

```
public class SharedController : Controller
    {
        public JsonResult UploadImage()
        {
            JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
            result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
            try
            {
                var file = Request.Files[0];
                var fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
                result.Data = new { Success = true, ImageURL = string.Format("/Content/images/{0}", fileName) };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                result.Data = new { Success = false, Message = ex.Message };
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: not sure i understand your question, so when you choose an image it will reload the page and all your entered data is lost? Also what does it mean by `it is not reloading the page if I am choosing files other than image file` what did u choose?

Comment: @HastaTamang Yes ,it is reloading the page when I am selecting the Image file ( i.e. jpg,.png etc.) only which is not expected. I don't want to reload the page.  Currently,I have enabled to select all the files. In that case ,when I am selecting files other than image file then page is not getting reloaded. Here I am selecting  .pdf file.

Comment: @HastaTamang This is happening after the alert message which present in the .done part of the ajax.

Comment: I tried your code and uploaded images jpg/png  it works without reloading the page. I hope that duplicate alert in done function is commented in your code as well?

Comment: @HastaTamang Yes duplicate alert code is commented.

Comment: I am sorry but i could not reproduce your issue

Comment: @HastaTamang Ok Thanks. I am checking if have done any silly mistakes. If I get the solution then I will post that.